# Azure LB in front of a Private VNet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer

I have a private VNet which is peered with the company network (we have the Route table and the virtual network gateway), now what I want to do is connect an LB to an existing VM in this network which has private and public IP already. The external LB should work as entry point from internet to the Private Network.

Now I've set up the LB with the probe, the Load Balancer rule and the Backend pool as per documentation. I've also tried to use both Basic and Standard sku. Also the Network Security Group allows all the ports I need but still I can't connect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A load balancer can either be external (with a public IP) or internal (VNET integrated).

However, you can just create two LBs - one external and one internal - that both point to the VM.

Comment: Yes I know but my issue is that the external Load Balancer doesn't work. Apparently can't connect to the VM at all. Again, my VM is in a Vnet which is peered with a private Network, could be this a problem?

Comment: Can you directly connect to your VM on it’s public IP address? If not, maybe something is wrong with your routing

Comment: Yes that's one of the problem, basically I can't connect to te VM from my pc but I can connect from another Azure VM for example.

Comment: For something wrong with the routing you mean the Azure Route Table? Actually I have it configured by someone else, it can be that the route doesn't allow the traffic to the LB ip?

Comment: For you to be able to connect to the VM directly (without the LB) you need to have a route to the internet. Check you effective routes when you click on the NIC in the azure portal

Comment: If you are referring to the NSG that's not the problem, I have the port open for inbound and outbound traffic and the effective rules confirm that. What I'm trying to say, since the VNET is peered with the private network of the company could be something else?

Comment: Routing, not NSG. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/diagnose-network-routing-problem